# Find the missing rows in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have the following `list` and `data.frame` .

```
 rows_i_need = c(letters)
 df1 = data.frame(a=c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g", "i", "j", "k"), 
      b=rnorm(9, 6, 2), 
      c=rnorm(9, 12, 3.5), 
      d=rnorm(9, 8, 3)
      )
```

How can I create a new list of the 'missing rows', so with output list:

```
 missing_rows = c("d", "h", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
```

Comment: You can do `setdiff(rows_i_need, df1$a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an approach with `match()`:

```
rows_i_need[-match(df1$a,rows_i_need)]
```

Output:

```
[1] "d" "h" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this...

missing_rows = rows_i_need[!rows_i_need %in% df1$a]